# PyTables EArray example fail

Tags: macos, macports, pytables

While trying to understand why my PyTables EArray doesn't work, I finally tested example file earray1.py from https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/tree/develop/examples
and it also gives error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "earray1.py", line 9, in <module>
array_c.append(numpy.array(['a' * 2, 'b' * 4], dtype='S8'))
File  "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tables/earray.py", line 214, in append
self._append(nparr)
File "tables/hdf5extension.pyx", line 1455, in tables.hdf5extension.Array._append (tables/hdf5extension.c:16160)
tables.exceptions.HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

File "H5D.c", line 908, in H5Dset_extent
not a dataset

End of HDF5 error back trace

Problems appending the elements
Closing remaining open files:earray1.h5...doneenter code here
```

As much as I get from this message, it is most likely related to an incompatible HDF5 version, but it shouldn't be this way I guess.

I'm running Mac OSX 10.10.5 with python 3.4.4 installed via port and py34-tables also installed via port. PyTables in it's documentation seems to refer to hdf5-1.8* but in my machine the hdf5 dependency for PyTables seem to be port package hdf5, which is version 1.10.

Can anyone confirm that PyTables actually works with hdf5 1.10? Better even would be confirmation that the version of tables that comes with port works.

Comment: Hello, I also stumbled onto some library incompatibilities. I solved them using the Anaconda distribution. Sorry, not really a direct response to your question, but it saved me a lot of pain!

Comment: Thanks for comment. I've never seriously considered anaconda, but indeed it could be the way to go for me as well.